# Android - logs from jar file

Tags: android, oauth, signpost

I am using the signpost library (JAR file) in my Android app to do OAuth.

I want to investigate the signature generation logic of signpost for the request token stage. I need to somehow insert some logs into the JAR file to print values of certain variables in the logic and possibly print some extra logs. Is it possible to add logs to a JAR file, or is there some other way to achieve the same result ?

Comment: if the source is provided then add log to the source code and make a new jar apart from that I see no alternative as for the signature generation logic having a log doesnot prove so helpful without the source